# Re-creating a python invocation

Tags: python, shell, escaping, shlex

Is it possible to patch together a copy-and-pastable invocation for a python program from the invoked program itself? It doesn't have to be exactly the same invocation string, but the arguments should parse to the same thing.

Note that `' '.join(sys.argv)` won't cut it, unfortunately. The main problem I have with this approach is that it won't properly quote arguments. Consider `dummy.py` with `import sys; print(sys.argv); print(' '.join(sys.argv))`

Running `python dummy.py "1 2"` prints:

```
['dummy.py', '1 2']
dummy.py 1 2
```

And of course if we copy the latter we'll get a different invocation. Wrapping each argument in quotes won't work either. Consider `dummy2.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
print(' '.join('"{}"'.format(s) for s in sys.argv))
```

This will break for:

```
python dummy2.py ' " breaking " '
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `shlex.quote`:

```
import sys
from shlex import quote

print(' '.join(quote(s) for s in sys.argv))
```

in shell:

```
python space_in_argv.py "aa bb" ' " breaking " '
```

yields:

```
space_in_argv.py 'aa bb' ' " breaking " '
```

you may also want to include `sys.executable`, see [more detail in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

Comment: neat! that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @VF1 may I known that what is your intent of this?

Comment: I am running experiments with a python script, specifying parameters via command line. This is useful to quickly re-create the experiment (by copying from a logfile)